# Prolog: Can prolog detect facts that does not exist yet?

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner in Prolog, and here is my question:

I want to build a KB that adds facts as it goes along.

In my initial KB, I do not have the fact: `selected(veggies).`

However, in my code, I want to do a validation based on whether the selected(..). fact exists (not only veggies, but others as well), is this possible in Prolog?

Something like:

```
if(selected(X)):
   ...
else: false.
```

Comment: You query `selected(veggies)`. If it exists, this succeeds. If it doesn't, it fails. If you query, `selected(Veg)` then Prolog will find all of the `Veg` that cause it to succeed.

Comment: If I query it without first writing the fact, it will result in: ERROR: Undefined procedure: selected/1 (DWIM could not correct goal). I think i'm doing something wrong.. I queried: selected(X).

Comment: `selected(veggies)` gives you that error because you evidently don't have any facts or predicates defined for `selected/1`. It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here. Do you have a static database of `selected` facts? Or are you intending to assert them dynamically?

Comment: If you have a dynamic database, you need to use the `dynamic/1` directive. For example, `:- dynamic(selected/1).` in your Prolog source.

Comment: hi! sorry for the late reply as i pulled an all nighter previously, yes the dynamic worked! thanks so much for the help :)

Comment: If you are using SWI-prolog, you might be interested in [`assert/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert%2f1) to "add facts". (see `asserta` and `assertz` as `assert` is deprecated)